# Autocompletion using CompletionItem.InsertText instead of CompletionItem.Label in Omnisharp VSSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, autocomplete, completionhandler, omnisharp

I'm trying to write an extension for VSCode with an auto-completion service, using the `OmniSharp.Extensions.LanguageServer` nuget package. I want to insert code snippets when the user selects a completion item.

It works if I set the `Label` property of the completion items to the text of my snippets. However, my labels now look ugly in the completion list because they have to contain linebreaks and tabs. So I was looking for another solution.

According to the [Vscode `CompletionItem` class documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#CompletionItem), it looks like I need to use the property `InsertText` instead of or in addition to `Label`:

> A string or snippet that should be inserted in a document when selecting this completion. When falsy, the `label` is used.

**Problem:**

In my case, even if I set the `InsertText` to something that is not falsy, VSCode will still insert the value of the `Label` property.

What could cause this behavior? Is this a bug in Omnisharp, or is there another configuration I'm not aware of that I have to set to force VSCode to insert the value of the `InsertText` instead of the value of the `Label`?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out: I also was using the `ComplitionItem.TextEdit` property. It caused the set `ComplitionItem.InsertText` property to be ignored. According to the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#CompletionItem), `ComplitionItem.TextEdit` is

> deprecated - Use `CompletionItem.InsertText` and `CompletionItem.Range` instead.